# how to get value of textbox passed into two different functions

Tags: html

My goal is to print: 
hi,  
RED pill selected 
-- if red pill was selected

my code here outputs:
Hi, undefined
RED pill selected.

I think the problem with my code lies within my form onsubmit , I am having trouble how do I put 2 functions on the onsubmit of form

here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
                function clickRed(){
                    var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName;
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Hi, " + txtName + "!"
                    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "RED pill selected!"
                    return false;
                }
                function clickBlue(){
                    var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName;
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Hi, " + txtName + "!"
                    document.getElementById("msg2").innerText = "BLUE pill selected."
                    return false;
                }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name='loginForm' onSubmit="" method='POST'></form>
            <div>
                <label for='username'>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="txtName" id="idName">
            </div>
            <br/>

                <input type="submit" onclick= "clickRed()" value="RED">
            <span id="blueContainer">
                <input type="submit" onclick= "clickBlue()" value="BLUE">
            </span>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <p id="msg"></p>
                <p id="msg2"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not you add script at the bottom?

Comment: i think there is no big difference with putting scrip at the top and at the bottom. Please correct me if I am wrong. But I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this:

```
var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName;
```

to this:

```
var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName.value;
```

and get rid of the errant closing `<\form>` tag at the end of this line:

```
<form name='loginForm' onSubmit="" method='POST'></form>
```

and implement `preventDefault()` as shown in the snippet which will stop the normal `submit` behavior.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
                function clickRed(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName.value;
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Hi, " + txtName + "!"
                    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "RED pill selected!"
                    return false;
                }
                function clickBlue(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName.value;
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Hi, " + txtName + "!"
                    document.getElementById("msg2").innerText = "BLUE pill selected."
                    return false;
                }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name='loginForm' onSubmit="" method='POST'>
            <div>
                <label for='username'>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="txtName" id="idName">
            </div>
            <br/>

                <input type="submit" onclick="clickRed(event)" value="RED">
            <span id="blueContainer">
                <input type="submit" onclick="clickBlue(event)" value="BLUE">
            </span>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <p id="msg"></p>
                <p id="msg2"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you are coming from reactjs,

Here is your mistake,

1. you used multiple form tag end
2. you should use onsubmit instance of onSubmit
3. you should make return false at form onsubmit event.
4. and using script at head it's also bad habit .

See the snippet code below.

```js
  function formSubmit(e){
                return false;
            }
            function clickRed(){
                var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName;
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Hi, " + txtName.value + "!"
                document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "RED pill selected!"
                return false;
            }
            function clickBlue(){
                var txtName = document.loginForm.txtName;
                document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Hi, " + txtName.value + "!"
                document.getElementById("msg2").innerText = "BLUE pill selected."
                return false;
            }
```

```html
 <form name='loginForm' onsubmit="return formSubmit()" method='POST'>
            <div>
                <label for='username'>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="txtName" id="idName">
            </div>
            <br/>

                <input type="submit" onclick= "clickRed()" value="RED">
            <span id="blueContainer">
                <input type="submit" onclick= "clickBlue()" value="BLUE">
            </span>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <p id="msg"></p>
                <p id="msg2"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```